# Custom environment with incorrect line breaking

Tags: environments, enumerate

First of all, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{boldenumerate}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]}
    {\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand\bolditem[1]{\item \textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{boldenumerate}
    \bolditem{Caption:} xxx fsdkjnfdskf sdnjdsnfmdns dnsmfndsmfnds nfdsmn fmssadasd-dnfm nsdmfn msndmnsdbfinsfdn
    \bolditem{Another caption:} yy
\end{boldenumerate}

\end{document}
```

In general, it does exactly what I want it to do. But unfortunately it exceeds the right side edge in some cases when hyphenation gets invoked:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my environment definition?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. There does not exist hyphernation patterns for what ever that language is. Btw you can use the kantlipsum package and its `\kant` comnand to get sample text in English (which is the default hyphernation pattern)

Comment: TeX never attempts hyphenation at “words” containing an explicit hyphen.

Comment: The fact is not that this word doesn't exist. Of course there is no correct hyphenation for "fdsfdsfsd...". (The same problem occurs with "normal words" that contain a hyphen.) But if the word is too long for the current line, shouldn't it be moved to the following line??? That's the behaviour I want to force.

Comment: No, that doesn't happen if you don't ask for ragged right typesetting.

Comment: But I observed this behaviour only within my boldenumerate environment. Never in the normal textflow.

Comment: OK, I have to admit that this behaviour also can occur in normal textflow. Is there no way to avoid such situations?

Comment: The non-hyphenating of explicitly hyphenated words is pretty weird and definitely something of a downside of TeX's algorithm. But I don't think there's much you can do about it, @egreg?

Comment: @cfr It's a precise choice made by Knuth. And I endorse it: in these cases, judgment has to be used for where to place a discretionary hyphen.

Comment: @egreg I think TeX would make a better decision than me, so I'd rather it was done automatically, just treating each hyphenated word as containing the hyphenation points it would otherwise have. I appreciate this would not always give an ideal result, but it would often give a better one than I actually get, because it is too easy to miss the spilt text. At least an automatic solution would get the text on the page. I understand that you might want to micromanage the results for some projects, but for everyday stuff, I'm usually in a hurry and overlook stuff. I'd rather have results readable.

Comment: @cfr: I’ve just read [this old comment of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414786/custom-environment-with-incorrect-line-breaking#comment1036584_414786), to which, however, I’m not going to reply since I assume you have meanwhile appreciated the rationale behind Knuth’s design decision.

Comment: @GuM Nope. Absolutely don't appreciate this one one bit.

Comment: @cfr: Consider the following: 1) By Knuth’s design, TeX marks every occurrence of an “overfull line” with a black rule, to help the reader to spot them all; but the thickness of this rule is customizable, and Leslie Lamport chose to disable this feature in LaTeX by making the thickness equal to zero. 2) Knuth’s idea was to force users to pay attention to every overfull line, because he felt that no automatic solution could be up to TeX’s high standards, and that human intervention was required. 3) You can always ask TeX to automatically cope with the issue by saying `\sloppy` (or equivalent).

Comment: @GuM I don't want `\sloppy`. I just want it to utilise otherwise standard hyphenation points in hyphenated words. And Knuth may have had time to inspect every line, but usually I don't. For a book, the design decision is reasonable. For teaching materials, it isn't. Lamport only disabled the feature in `final` mode, which is probably sensible, after all.

Comment: @cfr: 1) I didn’t dwell on LaTeX’s `draft` option because of the 600 character limit.  2) When TeX generates an overfull line, it has *already* tried *all* possible hyphenation points it can find in *every* word of the paragraph, and it has found, nonetheless, that the line-breaking task is impossible without getting at least one line whose badness exceeds the value of `\tolerance` (usually 200).  Knuth’s rationale is that, by fixing the latter, you tell TeX when you want it to give up automatic line-breaking (*with* hyphenation) and report the problem to you, for human intervention.

Comment: @GuM It hasn't tried all possible hyphenation points for hyphenated words because it only considers the explicit hyphenation points to be possible hyphenation points. I want it to try the other hyphenation points, too - as if the explicit hyphens were spaces. Then it would find hyphenation points. It doesn't not find them - it doesn't look for them because it won't count them. But using those hyphenation points is often the best solution and at least keeps stuff on the paper rather than sending it to never-never-land.

Comment: @cfr: Oh, dear!  It looks like we’ve been talking for two days about two completely different subjects!  But it’s my fault, I didn’t realize that you were spaeaking of hyphenation of words *that already contain an explicit hyphen*.  I think this has to do with the fact that, in English, such compound words are usually made up with “pieces” that are reasonably short, plus the fact that having both an explicit hyphen and of an implicit one in the same word might be distracting.  As you certainly know, for some languages the `babel` package make provisions for automatic hyphenation in such cases.

Comment: @GuM Oh, dear and welcome to the internet ;). Actually, I didn't know Babel did that. Interesting. It suggests it might be doable for English, too. I suggested above that there wasn't much could be done about it, but maybe I'm wrong if it is done in other languages. I do agree that there is some potential for distraction/confusion and that, ideally, it is best to look at each case. But I'd prefer TeX to issue a warning for that and still use the hyphenation points it can, because that's typically better than what I get and I frankly never know the hyphenation points, whereas TeX does :-).

Comment: @cfr: Yes, after saying `\usepackage[italian]{babel} \setactivedoublequote`, all I have to do is to write, say, `economico"-sociologico"-geopolitico`, and TeX will utilize all the hyphenation points it knows about in the line breaking algorithm; indeed, `\showhyphens{economico"-sociologico"-geopolitico}` returns `eco-no-mi-co-so-cio-lo-gi-co-geo-po-li-ti-co`.  I see no reason why the same could not be done in English too, but apparently nobody has ever felt this necessary, at least until now… :-)

Answer (score 2):

With the code you showed us you have to add possibly breaks to add by your own, if a word already contains an hyphen.  So instead your  `fmssadasd-dnfm` write for example `fms\-sad\-asd-dnfm` ( I guessed two possitions for a valid `-`) or for your word with hyphen in your answer `Pop-Operationen` write `Pop-Ope\-ra\-tio\-nen`.

The complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{boldenumerate}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]}
    {\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand\bolditem[1]{\item \textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea 
rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{boldenumerate}
  \bolditem{Caption:} xxx fsdkjnfdskf sdnjdsnfmdns dnsmfndsmfnds 
    nfdsmn fms\-sad\-asd-dnfm nsdmfn msndmnsdbfinsfdn
  \bolditem{Caption:} xxx fsdkjnfdskf sdnjdsnfmdns dnsmfndsmfnds 
    nfd Pop-Ope\-ra\-tio\-nen nsdmfn msndmnsdbfinsfdn
  \bolditem{Another caption:} yy
\end{boldenumerate}

\end{document}
```

and gives you the result:

[image]

## Solution for German language

It seems you are a German using German language:  Then you will use package `babel` in your code for language support.  With `babel` you can use `"=` to mark a fixed, always printed `-` in an german word, but other (automatic) hyphenations are allowed too.

So you will get with the following german MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside, openright, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % <=========================================

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext} % to get dummy text in used language, if supported

\newenvironment{boldenumerate}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]}
    {\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand\bolditem[1]{\item \textbf{#1}}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{boldenumerate}
  \bolditem{Caption:} xxx fsdkjnfdskf sdnjdsnfmdns dnsmfndsmfnds 
    nfdsmn fmssadasd"=dnfm nsdmfn msndmnsdbfinsfdn % <==================
  \bolditem{Caption:} xxx fsdkjnfdskf sdnjdsnfmdns dnsmfndsmfnds 
    nfd Pop"=Operationen nsdmfn msndmnsdbfinsfdn % <====================
  \bolditem{Another caption:} yy
\end{boldenumerate}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted as the most comprehensive answer (so it will no longer bumped to the homepage… ;-) , but we should acknowledge the OP’s priority at least for the solution for German, shouldn’t we?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, many other language definition files for the `babel` package, beside German, define the same shorthand to insert explicit hyphens between words without affecting TeX’s ability to hyphenate those words.  However, it is easy, with the help of Appendix H of *The TeXbook*, to write a small macro that does the same, without depending on external packages.

Indeed, TeX looks ahead for words to be hyphenated starting from every glue item in a horizontal list, so it suffices to add `\nobreak\hskip\z@skip` after the explicit hyphen: the `\nobreak` will prohibit a line break at the following glue, but that glue will “count” as a starting point for the lookahead notwithstanding.  Morevover, in order to permit hyphenation of the word that *precedes* the explicit hyphen, it is necessary, and sufficent, to insert between the word and the hyphen certain types of nodes, the “cheapest” of which is probably an empty `\vadjust` node.  So:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\+{\vadjust{}-\nobreak\hskip\z@skip}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\showhyphens{arithmetical-mathematical-geometrical}
\showhyphens{arithmetical\+mathematical\+geometrical}

This book treats of several complex problems that are
arithmetical\+mathematical\+geometrical in nature.  I~don't believe, however,
that such word as the compound adjective
``arithmetical\+mathematical\+geometrical'' exists in English: indeed, I've just
made it up.

\end{document}
```

Compare the output of the two `\showhyphens` commands

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 18--18
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 arithmetical-mathematical-geometrical

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--19
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 arith-meti-cal-math-e-mat-i-cal-ge-o-met-ri-cal
```

to check that everything works as expected.  You can also have a look at the output produced:

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out a workaround: The problem occured for the German word Pop-Operationen for example. Instead of `Pop-Operationen` I wrote `Pop"=Operationen` which additionally allows the common hyphenations of both words. In this special case I got

> "Pop-Operatio-
>
> nen"